# The input only display the last value in react

Tags: reactjs, forms

This is propably a stupid question but the input is only showing the last value, not the current.

```
  const handleChange = async (e: any) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    const newValue = value
    await setChartData({ ...chartData, [name]: newValue });
    console.log(chartData)
  }
```

If i tipe "h" he display nothing, if i type "hi" he display "h".

I've searched but didn't found duplications.

Answer (score 0):

would you please try this

```
const handleChange = async (e: any) => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log("value", value)
    await setChartData({ ...chartData, [name]: value });
    console.log(chartData)
}
```